# How can I find the IP of a device not on my network but is connected to my Laptop via ethernet cat5 cable?

Tags: powershell, networking, lan

I need to find out the devices IP so that I can manually set my laptops computer to the devices network and reconfigure the devices IP. I have only its MAC address which was acquired from the devices label. I am new to networking trouble shooting. I am hoping to do this using Windows PowerShell, but I also have wireshark and linux available.

Comment: I think for clarity you should specify if they are in the same subnet. A device with an IP address of 192.168.1.x on a subnet of 255.255.255.0 will not typically communicate on a separate subnet if the IP of the communicating device is on 192.169.2.x without having additional network settings added or a device routing traffic between them.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you if the firewall is not active on that device.

In one cmd.exe ping your broadcast address, assuming your ip is 192.168.0.X

```
 ping -t 192.168.0.255
```

In another cmd.exe window type arp -A to see your ARP table aka MAC to IP address table, because you mention you have the MAC you should be able to see the IP

```
arp -A
```

How it works? This will send ping packets to the broadcast address, everybody on your broadcast domain will see the packet and respond to it, once they respond they will be added to your computer ARP table.